# How to build pivot table through linq using c#

Tags: linq, pivot

I have got this datatable in my c# code:

```
Date     | Employee | Job1 | Job2 |  Job3 |
---------|----------|------|------|-------|
1/1/2012 | A        | 1.00 | 1    |  1    |
1/1/2012 | B        | 2.5  | 2    |  2    |
1/1/2012 | C        | 2.89 | 1    |  4    |
1/1/2012 | D        | 4.11 | 2    |  1    |
1/2/2012 | A        | 3    | 2    |  5    |
1/2/2012 | B        | 2    | 2    |  2    |
1/2/2012 | C        | 3    | 3    |  3    |
1/2/2012 | D        | 1    | 1    |  1    |
1/3/2012 | A        | 5    | 5    |  5    |
1/3/2012 | B        | 2    | 2    |  6    |
1/3/2012 | C        | 1    | 1    |  1    |
1/3/2012 | D        | 2    | 3    |  4    |
2/1/2012 | A        | 2    | 2    |  2    |
2/1/2012 | B        | 5    | 5    |  2    |
2/1/2012 | D        | 2    | 2    |  2    |
2/2/2012 | A        | 3    | 3    |  3    |
2/2/2012 | B        | 2    | 3    |  3    |
3/1/2012 | A        | 4    | 4    |  2    |
```

Now I want to create another DataTable which would look like this:

```
Job1    
Employee | 1/1/2012 | 1/2/2012 | 1/3/2012 | 2/1/2012 | 2/2/2012 |
---------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
A        | 1.00     | 3        | 5        | 2        | 3        |
B        | 2.50     | 2        | 2        | 5        | 2        |
C        | 2.89     | 3        | 1        | -        |          |
D        | 4.11     | 1        | 2        | 2        |          |
Total    | 10.50    | 9        | 10       | 9        | 5        |
```

Please suggest how to make this pivot table using Linq and C#.

Comment: No offense to anyone, I think the motto "what you tried" is not necessarily useful for all direct questions.
How can we show that we tried while we do not have a clue how to proceed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Pivot Table from a DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981120/create-a-pivot-table-from-a-datatable)

Answer (score 5):

```
var query = from foo in db.Foos
            group foo by foo.Date into g
            select new {
                Date = g.Key,
                A = g.Where(x => x.Employee == "A").Sum(x => x.Job1),
                B = g.Where(x => x.Employee == "B").Sum(x => x.Job1),
                C = g.Where(x => x.Employee == "C").Sum(x => x.Job1),
                D = g.Where(x => x.Employee == "D").Sum(x => x.Job1),
                Total = g.Sum(x => x.Job1)
            };
```

You can also apply `OrderBy(x => x.Date)` to query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now as i do not know much about linq, my question is what is db.foos? Also i cannot hard-code the employee name as they would be dynamic.

Comment: @user1254053 well, how would I know that from your question? You even didn't specify name of table in database, that's why I used *Foo*. And `db` variable is your `DbContext` (I believe you use EF 4.1 or later).

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The employee names are static in your answer, is it possible to make dynamic columns in it, because i dont know employee names, and i cant hard code them.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with LINQ due to the dynamic nature of the columns. LINQ to SQL needs a static way to map result set fields to property values. Instead, you can look into the `PIVOT` SQL statement and fill the results into a `DataTable`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx