# Put value in datatable group by week

Tags: linq, pivot, linq-to-objects

I have a datatable which comprises values from 1st January to march, something like this:

```
DATE        Employer    Job1    Job2
1/4/2013        A        1.3    2
1/4/2013        B        2.5    6
1/6/2013        C        3.7    2.4
1/7/2013        D        11 
1/7/2013        F        334    0
1/8/2013        A        1.87   1
1/8/2013        B        6.85   2
1/9/2013        C        58     226
1/16/2013       A        9.43   1.45
1/16/2013       B        5.27   0.6
1/122/2013      C        45.4   5
1/23/2013       A        44     4.78
1/29/2013       B        45     40  
2/2/2013        C        45     54.12
2/2/2013        D         7     4.4587
2/3/2013        F        265    11.486
```

Update:

```
DataTable datatable = new DataTable("Employee");

datatable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
datatable.Columns.Add("Employee", typeof(string));
datatable.Columns.Add("Job1", typeof(double));
datatable.Columns.Add("Job2", typeof(double));

datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/4/2013", "A", 1.3, 2 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/4/2013", "B", 2.5, 6 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/6/2013", "C", 3.7, 2.4 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/7/2013", "D", 11, 0.0 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/7/2013", "F", 334, 0 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/8/2013", "A", 1.87, 1 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/8/2013", "B", 6.85, 2 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/9/2013", "C", 58, 226 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/16/2013", "A", 9.43, 1.45 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/16/2013", "B", 5.27, 0.6 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/22/2013", "C", 45.4, 5 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/23/2013", "A", 44, 4.78 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "1/29/2013", "B", 45, 40 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "2/2/2013", "C", 45, 54.12 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "2/2/2013", "D", 7, 4.4587 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "2/3/2013", "F", "265", 11.486 });
datatable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "3/3/2013", "A", "25", 28.124 });
```

I want to sum the values for job1 week wise where week starts from Monday to Sunday. This is the code I have written so far.

```
DateTime minDate = datatable.AsEnumerable()
        .Min(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")));

DateTime startDate = minDate.Date.Date.AddDays(+((6 + minDate.DayOfWeek
                                                    - DayOfWeek.Monday) % 7));

DateTime nextDate = startDate.AddDays(6);

DateTime maxDate = datatable.AsEnumerable()
        .Max(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")));

while (nextDate < maxDate)
{
    var weekEmpGroups = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Row = r,
        Employee = r.Field<String>("Employee"),
        Date = DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")) 
        // week = minDate.Date.Date.AddDays(+((6 + minDate.DayOfWeek
                                                 - DayOfWeek.Monday) % 7))
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Employee);

DataTable dtWeeklyResults = new DataTable();
dtWeeklyResults.Columns.Add("Employee", typeof(string));
var dtf = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

double weekCount = 0.0;
string expression;
DataRow[] foundRows;

foreach (var empGroup in weekEmpGroups)
{
    string employee = empGroup.Key;
    var newRow = dtWeeklyResults.Rows.Add();
    newRow["Employee"] = employee;                        

    expression = "Employee=" + employee + " AND Date Between " + startDate
               + " And " + nextDate;
    foundRows = datatable.Select(expression);

    if (foundRows.Length > 0)
    {
        // add values using linq
    }

}
```

Please suggest if this is correct way to do this and also how to add all values week wise? The result should look like this for Job1:

```
Employee  1/7-1/13    1/14-1/20    1/21-1/27    1/28-2/3  and so on...
A        sum of values for this 7 days
B
C
D
```

Can anybody suggest how to achieve this by LINQ?

Comment: It would be much easier to get an answer if you've prepared c# code that creates your sample `DataTable` :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build pivot table through linq using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495124/how-to-build-pivot-table-through-linq-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Please do not post (roughly) the same question twice. Edit the previous one to bring it into attention or set a bounty on it.

Comment: Thank you Gert Arnold for looking at my question. That question is way too different with respect to this question. There the values had to be shown as pivot with no calculation and above all i did not received a solution as expected. Here it is different in as way is - i want to add a group by clause to show a sum of Job1 values for any employee in a given date range which is a week.

Comment: Yes but I think the pivoting is... pivotal here. Once you've got a data-independent method for pivoting you can use it for any data. In you previous question I also (indirectly) linked to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46486/Pivoting-DataTable-Simplified. Didn't that post help you? You should try to separate the task - pivoting and data retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody have the same requirement that is to show the results week wise then here is the code:

```
          private static DataTable GetWeeklyColumnsAndData(DataTable datatable, string resultFor)
         {
            DateTime minDate = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                               .Min(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")));

            DateTime maxDate = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                               .Max(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")));

            var distinctValues = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(row => new
                                 {
                                    Employee = row.Field<string>("Employee")
                                 })
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .ToList();

           int totalEmployeeCount = System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(distinctValues);

           DataTable resultDt = new DataTable();
           resultDt.Columns.Add("Employee", typeof(string));

           DateTime firstMonday = (minDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) ? minDate : GetNextWeekday(minDate, DayOfWeek.Monday);

           DateTime startingMonday = firstMonday;

           // add columns first
           while (firstMonday < maxDate)
           {
             string weekName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", firstMonday.ToString("M/d", ci), firstMonday.AddDays(6).ToString("M/d", ci));
             resultDt.Columns.Add(weekName, typeof(string));
             firstMonday = firstMonday.AddDays(7);
           }

           for (int row = 0; row < totalEmployeeCount; row++)
           {
                            DateTime startDate = startingMonday;
                            DateTime endDate = startingMonday.AddDays(6);

                            DataRow newRow = resultDt.NewRow();

                            string employee = distinctValues[row].Employee.ToString();

                            // first column for entity                
                            newRow[0] = employee;

                            for (int col = 1; col < resultDt.Columns.Count; col++)
                            {
                                bool isBlank = false;
                                double total = 0;
                                string formattedMonday = endDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
                                string expression = String.Format("Employee = '{0}' AND DATE >= #{1}# AND DATE <= #{2}#", employee, startDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy"), formattedMonday);

                                DataView dv = datatable.DefaultView;
                                dv.RowFilter = expression;
                                if (dv.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
                                    {
                                        DataRow r = rowView.Row;
                                        string value = r[resultFor].ToString();
                                        if (value != "")
                                        {
                                            total += Convert.ToDouble(value);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            isBlank = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    isBlank = true;
                                }

                                if (total == 0 && isBlank)
                                {
                                    newRow[col] = "";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    newRow[col] = total;
                                }
                                startDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
                                endDate = startDate.AddDays(6);
                            }

                            resultDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
                        }

                        return resultDt;
         }



       public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, DayOfWeek day)
       {
             // The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
              int daysToAdd = ((int)day - (int)start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
              return start.AddDays(daysToAdd);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

***Helper methods***

```
private static string GetColumnName(int weekNumber)
{
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);

    int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Monday - jan1.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime firstMonday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);

    var cal = ci.Calendar;
    int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstMonday, ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);

    if (firstWeek <= 1)
    {
        weekNumber -= 1;
    }

    DateTime result = firstMonday.AddDays((weekNumber-1) * 7);

    return string.Format("{0}-{1}", result.ToString("M/d", ci), result.AddDays(6).ToString("M/d", ci));
}

private static int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime value)
{
    return ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(value, ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
}
```

***`CultureInfo` instance***

```
static CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

***Logic***

```
// load parsed data from DataTable to a list
var data = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("Date"), ci),
                    Employee = row.Field<string>("Employee"),
                    Value = row.Field<double>("Job1")
                }).ToList();

// find min/max date and week number
var minDateTime = data.Select(i => i.Date).Min();
var maxDateTime = data.Select(i => i.Date).Max();
var minWeekNumber = GetWeekOfYear(minDateTime);
var maxWeekNumber = GetWeekOfYear(maxDateTime);

// prepare result DataTable
var resultDt = new DataTable("Job1");
resultDt.Columns.Add("Employee", typeof(string));
for (int i = minWeekNumber; i <= maxWeekNumber; i++)
    resultDt.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(double));

// prepare grouped data query
var employeeData = from d in data
                    group d by d.Employee into g
                    select new
                        {
                            Employee = g.Key,
                            Items = g.GroupBy(x => GetWeekOfYear(x.Date))
                                    .Select(x => new
                                    {
                                        Week = x.Key,
                                        Value = x.Sum(xx => xx.Value)
                                    })
                        };

// iterate over query results and fill resultsDt
foreach (var e in employeeData)
{
    var newRow = resultDt.NewRow();
    newRow["Employee"] = e.Employee;
    foreach (var d in e.Items)
        newRow[d.Week.ToString()] = d.Value;
    resultDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

// change column names from week numbers to proper start-end dates
foreach(DataColumn col in resultDt.Columns)
{
    int weekNumber;
    if (int.TryParse(col.ColumnName, out weekNumber))
    col.ColumnName = GetColumnName(weekNumber);
}
```

***Results:***

```
Job1
Employee  1/7-1/13  1/14-1/20  1/21-1/27  1/28-2/3  2/4-2/10  2/11-2/17  2/18-2/24  2/25-3/3  3/4-3/10  3/11-3/
A         1,3         1,87       9,43        44                                                            2
B         2,5         6,85       5,27                  45
C                     61,7                   45,4      45
D                     11                                7
F                    334                                         265
```

Comment: Thank you MarcinJuraszek, much appreciated! BTW what is "ci" in the above code, is this a class/reference i need to add?

Comment: Is this CultureInfo.CurrentCulture variable?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's `en-us` `CultureInfo` object - I used it because your dates are all in `en-us` format.

Comment: Thanks a lot MarcinJuraszek! This is good and works well except that either the column names are not correct (though they seems to be perfect) or the sum values are in wrong column. For ex. the 1/14-1/20 sum values are in fact should come in 1/7-1/13

Comment: Also, did you noticed that in date range 7 jan to 13 jan especially for employee "C" the value should be 58 but it comes to 61.7 (which is 6 jan + 9 Jan). Any idea why it is adding 6 jan value when our week starts from 7? Other values seems to be fine.

Comment: Thank you for all your help MarcinJuraszek. As mentioned above - in date range 7 jan to 13 jan for employee "C" the value should be 58 but it shows 61.7 (which is 6 jan (3.7) + 9 Jan (58)). Any idea why it is adding 6 jan value when our week starts from 7? Do you think i should add time component just to be sure that it does not add Jan 6 value in 1/7-1/13 date range.

Comment: That's because Sunday is default `FirstDayOfWeek` for `en-US` culture. Add `ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;` before all logic and it should work fine.

Comment: I want to start the columns from 1/7-1/13 i.e. it should start with first monday found in the datatable till the end. My results shows 12/31-1/6 as first column. Please suggest what should i change in the above code so that it ignores all the previous dates before monday. Thanks