# TRANSFORM Pivot usin Linq

Tags: c#, linq, pivot-table

I have record in below format and I want to pivot using linq , can you please help me that how to pivot data using Linq.

[image: Records]

[image: Result]

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495124/how-to-build-pivot-table-through-linq-using-c-sharp  ??

Comment: @ViSu:Pivot using Linq

Comment: -1: It is unclear what you are asking, do you mean you want to sort data? if so, what have you tried

Comment: @Sayse: i want PIVOT using Linq

Comment: @Sayse: If you are unable to understand then why you giving minus mark, first try to understand and then take action, i am asking PIVOT using Linq.

Comment: Your clarification of "I'm trying to PIVOT using LINQ" is "I'm trying to PIVOT using LINQ". That's not actually clarifying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
var userIds = table.Select(row => row.userid).Distinct();
var checkTimes = table.Select(row => row.CheckTime).Distinct();

var pivotTable =
    from userid in userIds
    select new {
        userid,
        attflags = checkTimes.Select(checkTime =>
            table.Where(row => row.userid == userid && row.CheckTime == checkTime)
                 .Select(row => row.attflag)
                 .DefaultIfEmpty("-")
                 .FirstOrDefault())
    };

 Console.WriteLine("userid\t" + String.Join("\t", checkTimes));
 foreach (var pivotRow in pivotTable)
     Console.WriteLine(pivotRow.userid + "\t" + String.Join("\t", pivotRow.attflags));
```

Comment: So many thanks Andrew, this is good solution, I want to summery (Count of attflag like(P, A, HP)) at the last with new columns. how to do please..