# C# Store returned sql data to be output as table

Tags: c#, sql

Users fill out a form. Each saved form has a unique ID. Each field in the form has a unique ID. Each response has a unique ID. Example returned data (edit: from sql query):

```
Form ID     Form Field ID     Response ID     Response
1           1                 1               Response to Q1.
1           2                 2               Response to Q2.
...
2           1                 10              2nd response to Q1.
2           2                 11              2nd response to Q2.
...
3           1                 20              3rd response to Q1.
3           2                 21              3rd response to Q2.
```

When the data is output, it needs to look like this:

```
Q1                    Q2                      ...     Qn
Response to Q1        Response to Q2          ...     Response to Qn
2nd response to Q1.   2nd response to Q2.     ...     2nd response to QN
3rd response to Q1.   3rd response to Q2.     ...     3rd response to QN
```

I've tried looking at using Dictionary:

```
var array_report_data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
```

And adding the data like this:

```
array_report_data[form_id][form_field_id]["response_id"] = 1;
array_report_data[form_id][form_field_id]["response"] = "Response to Q1.";
```

But I can't loop through the way I would in PHP. I'm trying to learn the proper way to do this in C#, but I have no clue where to start. I believe my biggest problem is how I'm trying to store the data (in Dictionary), which seems to be an incorrect way to do this.

I should mention that the final table is being generated by an onclick event, so I'm using jquery to make an ajax call and doing all the heavy lifting in an asmx page.

EDIT: How is the original data retrieved:

```
SELECT 
    [qw_forms_saved_id], 
    [qw_form_fields_id], 
    [qw_forms_saved_fields_id],
    [qw_form_field_response]
FROM 
    [qw_forms_saved]
WHERE
    [eff_end_dt] IS NULL AND
    [eff_end_dt] IS NULL
ORDER BY
    [qw_forms_saved_id] ASC,
    [qw_form_fields_id] ASC
```

Comment: Do you have your data output by some sql query? Do you have control of that query, or you are bound by input format, and need to convert it to target format? Where input is stored - data table, list of objects? Can you attach code sample which retrieve original data?

Comment: @Alexander - Data is output by sql query. I am pretty much bound by that and need to convert it to target format.

Comment: Try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495124/how-to-build-pivot-table-through-linq-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Darek - Thank you for the link. So basically, look at using linq? I'm not familiar with it, so I will take a look at that.

Comment: Kindly mark an answer if it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @Darek - Working through sample below. Will mark it if/when I get it all figured out (or post what worked). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample based on test data should get you started.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class Program
    {
        #region Methods

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region data

            var data = new List<FormData>
                       {
                           new FormData
                           {
                               FormId = 1,
                               FormFieldId = 1,
                               ResponseId = 1,
                               Response = "Response to Q1."
                           },
                           new FormData
                           {
                               FormId = 1,
                               FormFieldId = 2,
                               ResponseId = 2,
                               Response = "Response to Q2."
                           },
                           new FormData
                           {
                               FormId = 2,
                               FormFieldId = 1,
                               ResponseId = 10,
                               Response = "2nd Response to Q1."
                           },
                           new FormData
                           {
                               FormId = 2,
                               FormFieldId = 2,
                               ResponseId = 11,
                               Response = "2nd Response to Q2."
                           },
                           new FormData
                           {
                               FormId = 3,
                               FormFieldId = 1,
                               ResponseId = 20,
                               Response = "3rd Response to Q1."
                           },
                           new FormData
                           {
                               FormId = 3,
                               FormFieldId = 2,
                               ResponseId = 21,
                               Response = "3rd Response to Q2."
                           },
                       };

            #endregion

            var groups = data.GroupBy(g => g.FormFieldId).Select(
                s => new
                     {
                         s.Key,
                         Answers = s.Select(s2 => s2.Response).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(groups.Select(g => "Q" + g.Key.ToString("###").PadRight(29))));
            int maxRows = groups.Max(m => m.Answers.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(groups.Select(s1 => (i < s1.Answers.Count ? s1.Answers[i] : string.Empty).PadRight(30))));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        private class FormData
        {
            #region Public Properties

            public int FormFieldId { get; set; }

            public int FormId { get; set; }

            public string Response { get; set; }

            public int ResponseId { get; set; }

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Q1                            Q2
Response to Q1.               Response to Q2.
2nd Response to Q1.           2nd Response to Q2.
3rd Response to Q1.           3rd Response to Q2.
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for this sample. "Got me started" as you said. Minor changes to fit exactly how I need. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this in sql:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    Form_ID INT,
    Form_Field_ID INT, 
    Response_ID INT,
    Response VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
( Form_ID, Form_Field_ID, Response_ID, Response )
VALUES
(1,           1,                 1,               'Response to Q1.'),
(1,           2,                 2,               'Response to Q2.'),
(2,           1,                 10,              '2nd response to Q1.'),
(2,           2,                 11,              '2nd response to Q2.'),
(3,           1,                 20,              '3rd response to Q1.'),
(3,           2,                 21,              '3rd response to Q2.')

SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN d.Rank = 1 THEN d.Response END) Q1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN d.Rank = 2 THEN d.Response END) Q2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN d.Rank = 3 THEN d.Response END) Q3
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Form_Field_ID ORDER BY Response_ID) Rank
    FROM @MyTable
) d
GROUP BY Form_Field_ID
```

You would have to add a column for each level of responses. If you expect always 3 then this could be simple for you to achieve.