# Grouping rows for calculation using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I have a c# program that I am programing where someone inputs production for the whole day like this:

```
Date      | Part Number | Mold Num | Machine Num |  Total Parts  |Cycle  
2/12/2016 | 1185-5B8    |  6580    | 12          |   220         |  56  
2/12/2016 | 2249300     |  7797    | 36          |   600         |  13  
2/12/2016 | 146865      |  5096789 | 12          |   500         |  15  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  7787    | 56          |   300         |  34  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  787     | 54          |   360         |  36  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  777     | 56          |   500         |  46  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  87      | 54          |   400         |  44
```

I then calculate a machine usage (MU) for each entry like so:

```
Date      | Part Number | Mold Num | Machine Num |  MU  
2/12/2016 | 1185-5B8    |  6580    | 12          |  .428            
2/12/2016 | 2249300     |  7797    | 36          |  .271            
2/12/2016 | 146865      |  5096789 | 12          |  .260            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  7787    | 56          |  .354            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  787     | 54          |  .45            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  777     | 56          |  .799            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  87      | 54          |  .611
```

What I want to do is to make something like a pivot table and it takes all similar dates/Mold Numbers/Machine Numbers and makes an average the MU and display it in any way that I want. Example:

```
Date      |  MU
2/12/2016 |  32.0%
2/16/2016 |  55.4%
```

or

```
Machine Num. | MU 
    12       | 34.4%
    36       | 27.1%
    54       | 53.0%
    56       | 57.6%
```

etc. Basically I want it to be variable and to show whatever the person that is looking at it needs. I have looked for ways of doing this but they either did not make sense or not quite what I was looking for. Please keep in mind that I am very new to c# and LINQ to SQL

Comment: I'd advise against using Linq to SQL as it isn't very mature, instead use Linq to EntityFramework.

Comment: So what have you tried and what have you read that did not make sense?

Comment: @trailmax [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495124/how-to-build-pivot-table-through-linq-using-c-sharp) is what I tried however I could not figure out how to make it change based on what the user wanted.

Comment: @Aron Whats the difference between the two from what I've read they are very similar. What benefit do I get from using one rather than the other