# Creating a Pivot table in C#

Tags: c#, linq

In my c# program I have someone input production for the whole day and I calculate machine usage (MU) like so:

```
Date      | Part Number | Mold Num | Machine Num |  MU  
2/12/2016 | 1185-5B8    |  6580    | 12          |  .428            
2/12/2016 | 2249300     |  7797    | 36          |  .271            
2/12/2016 | 146865      |  5096789 | 12          |  .260            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  7787    | 56          |  .354            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  787     | 54          |  .45            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  777     | 56          |  .799            
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  87      | 54          |  .611
```

All of this data is in my SQL server and what I want to do is to make something like a pivot table and it takes all similar dates/Mold Numbers/Machine Numbers and makes an average the MU and display it in any way that the user wants. Example:

```
Date      |  MU
2/12/2016 |  32.0%
2/16/2016 |  55.4%
```

or

```
Machine Num. | MU 
12       | 34.4%
36       | 27.1%
54       | 53.0%
56       | 57.6%
```

etc. Basically I want it to be variable and to show whatever the person that is looking at it needs. I want to keep it in my c# program but I can use LINQ to SQL. Please keep in mind that I am very new to c# and LINQ to SQL.

I did try to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981120/create-a-pivot-table-from-a-datatable) but it was not exactly what I wanted to do. I also could not figure out how I was going to display it on the windows form nor how to change what was in each column.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't sound like a pivot table.  It just sounds like you want to group by something and then do an average.  A Pivot table changes values in a cell into column names.

Comment: @juharr I used a pivot table when I was doing it in excel and was the only way I could think of describing it

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to build pivot table with row dimension (Date, Machine Num), without column dimension and with average by MU.

You can easily do that with help of NReco PivotData library:

```
var pivotData = new PivotData(
    new string[] {"Date","Machine Num"},
    new AverageAggregatorFactory("MU"),
    new DataTableReader(t) );  // just a sample - you can use DB data reader
var pivotTable = new PivotTable(
    new []{"Date"}, // row dimension(s)
    new [0], // column dimension(s)
    pivotData );
// use pivotTable.RowKeys and indexer for accessing pivot table values
```

PivotData library can be used for free (I'm an author), and you can download examples package on the component's page. Also you may check advanced PivotData Toolkit components (for rendering pivot table to HTML/CSV/Excel/PDF, aggregating data on DB level with GROUP BY and many others), but they are not free.

Comment: Great, I didn't know that tool. Just FYI, the first sample on your page (online c# pivot table demo) looks to be incorrect - rows=[Country,year] and columns=[Products].

Comment: @CetinBasoz hm just checked - it seems correct. Could you contact me and explain why it is incorrect? Maybe I've missed something trivial...

Comment: First one says "Rows=[Country], Columns=[Year], Measure=[Sales Count]". However pivottable shows "Rows=[Country,Year], Columns=[Product]".

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, what you want isn't a pivot table, as already mentioned by @juharr.
For sqlite, this sould be accomplished with the following statement. (I assume the table name is `tmp`, and what you want is the sum of `MU` with each `MachineNUm`, naming it with `SMU`).

```
SELECT MachineNum,SUM(MU) AS SMU From tmp GROUP BY MachineNum ORDER BY MachineNum;
```

Hope it helps.